# Chrome for Mobile shows weird pixel like grid on elements that have background color of #505050

Tags: html, css

I've noticed some really strange grid that is sitting almost like background image on elements that have `background-color: #505050` (shade of grey). Actually that grid is showing also when element has similar (near) hex value like that one.

Tested on couple of android mobile devices that have older version of chrome.
 Namely `chrome-57.0-xxxxxxxxx`.

The only thing that I've noticed is similar shades of gray are used by chrome developer tools.

```css
.grey {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #333333;
  
}
.height500{
  
  height:500px;
}
.grey50 {
    
  
    height:150px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-color: #505050;
    
}
.size150{
   height:150px;
   margin-top:50px;
   margin-left: 50px;
   width: 150px;
}
.round {
  
   border-radius: 75px;
}
.grey55 {
  
    background-color: #555555;
}
```

```html
<div class="grey height500"> 
    <div class="grey50 size150"> grey50
       <div class="grey50 round size150"> grey50 round  </div>
       <div class="grey55 size150"> grey55</div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Can anyone confirm this and why would this be the case?

Comment: @Paulie_D I do not think this is a code error. More like a rendering issue.

Comment: Yes, but what is the cause of this ... For now it renders couple of shades of grey unusable.

Comment: Have you tested on other browsers, like Firefox, or the native one ?

Comment: Yes. Only Chrome for Mobile Devices (like Android ) have this issue. Desktop versions **do not**. Firefox for Mobile is also fine.